# Removing select options with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following webpage that has a countries dropdown and I need to remove the OFAC countries.

https://sk199.infusionsoft.com/app/orderForms/VUM-Monthly

I cant seem to figure out the right jQuery to use to remove the options.  The following code works if you click the credit card button and then refresh the page:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    function modifyContries(country) {
    sel1 = document.forms.orderForm.country;

    len1 = sel1.options.length;
    for (i=0;i<len1 ;i++ )
    {
    if (sel1.options[i].value == country)
    {
    sel1.options[i] = null;
    //or
    //sel1.remove(i);
    break;
    }
    }
    }
    modifyContries("Iran");
    modifyContries("Iraq");
    modifyContries("Libya");
    modifyContries("North Korea");
    modifyContries("Côte D'Ivoire");
    modifyContries("Congo");
    modifyContries("Liberia");
    modifyContries("Sudan");
    modifyContries("Syria");
    modifyContries("Zimbabwe");
    });
    </script>
```

I did try changing to the change() of the button, but that doesn't seem to fire at all.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#checkoutWithCreditCardLink').change(function(){         
    function modifyContries(country) {
    sel1 = document.forms.orderForm.country;

     len1 =sel1.options.length;
     for (i=0;i<len1 ;i++ )
     {
     if (sel1.options[i].value == country)
     {
     sel1.options[i] = null;
     //or
     //sel1.remove(i);
     break;
     }
     }
    }
    modifyContries("Iran");
    modifyContries("Iraq");
    modifyContries("Libya");
    modifyContries("North Korea");
    modifyContries("Côte D'Ivoire");
    modifyContries("Congo");
    modifyContries("Liberia");
    modifyContries("Sudan");
    modifyContries("Syria");
    modifyContries("Zimbabwe");
    });
    </script>
```

I should also mention that this a hosted form and I can only add script tags in the certain sections of the body, nothing in head. I can make this work when there is no button toggling the payment information block.

I need a way to make sure the OFAC countries are removed, TIA!

Comment: #checkoutWithCreditCardLink is button, right? So 'click' is the event you need (not 'change'). Then, you can try replacing "sel1.remove(i);" by "$(sel1).remove(i);". EDIT: use ne1410s' answer ^^

Comment: its a link...  <a id="checkoutWithCreditCardLinkPreview" onclick="javascript:Infusion.Ecomm.OrderForms.selectPaymentType('creditcard');Infusion.Ecomm.OrderForms.ajaxSubmitForm('orderForm', false, 0, '', 'VUM-Monthly', 'RENDER_ORDER_FORM',
                        ['ORDER_FORM_BILLING_ENTRY', 'PAYMENT_SELECTION', 'ORDER_FORM_SHIPPING_ENTRY', 'SHIPPING_OPTIONS', 'CHECKOUT_LINKS']);" class="continueButton">Pay with Credit Card</a>

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pick the country out more concisely, as follows:

```
$("select#country option[value='CountryX']").remove();
```

This is jQuery for "delete all the `<option>`s within the `<select>`s with id = 'country' (as is the case), which have a `value = 'CountryX'`.

**Update:**

You should place the above within an appropriate handler - e.g.

```
$("a#checkoutWithCreditCardLinkPreview").click(function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: I updated the example page to reflect the suggest, and it doesn't work as expected.  It will remove the option only after the button is clicked and then the page is refreshed.  <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery("select#country option[value='Iran']").remove();

});
</script>

Comment: I have updated my answer in accordance with @Nicolas 's comment - attaching to the appropriate event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Example :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Remove option values</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select class="regula-validation checkout" data-constraints="@Required(label=&quot;Billing Country&quot;, groups=[customer])" data-on="Component.Select" id="country" name="country">
        <option value="">Please select one</option>
        <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
        <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
        <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
        <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
        <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
        <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
        <option value="Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
        <option value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
        <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
        <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
        <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="Australia">Australia</option>
        <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
        <option value="Åland Islands">Åland Islands</option>
        <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
        <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
        <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
        <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
        <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
        <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
        <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
        <option value="Belize">Belize</option>
        <option value="Benin">Benin</option>
        <option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
        <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
        <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
        <option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
        <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
        <option value="Bouvet Island">Bouvet Island</option>
        <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
        <option value="British Indian Ocean Territory">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
        <option value="Brunei Darussalam">Brunei Darussalam</option>
        <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
        <option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
        <option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
        <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
        <option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
        <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
        <option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option>
        <option value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option>
        <option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option>
        <option value="Chad">Chad</option>
        <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
        <option value="China">China</option>
        <option value="Christmas Island">Christmas Island</option>
        <option value="Cocos (Keeling) Islands">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
        <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
        <option value="Comoros">Comoros</option>
        <option value="Democratic Republic Of Congo">Democratic Republic Of Congo</option>
        <option value="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</option>
        <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
        <option value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
        <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
        <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
        <option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>
        <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
        <option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
        <option value="Dominica">Dominica</option>
        <option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
        <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
        <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
        <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
        <option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
        <option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
        <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
        <option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
        <option value="Falkland Islands">Falkland Islands</option>
        <option value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option>
        <option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
        <option value="Finland">Finland</option>
        <option value="France">France</option>
        <option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option>
        <option value="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</option>
        <option value="French Southern Territories">French Southern Territories</option>
        <option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
        <option value="Gambia">Gambia</option>
        <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
        <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
        <option value="Ghana">Ghana</option>
        <option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>
        <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
        <option value="Greenland">Greenland</option>
        <option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
        <option value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option>
        <option value="Guam">Guam</option>
        <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
        <option value="Guernsey">Guernsey</option>
        <option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
        <option value="Guinea-Bissau">Guinea-Bissau</option>
        <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
        <option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
        <option value="Heard and McDonald Islands">Heard and McDonald Islands</option>
        <option value="Holy See (Vatican City State)">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
        <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
        <option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option>
        <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
        <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
        <option value="India">India</option>
        <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
        <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
        <option value="Isle of Man">Isle of Man</option>
        <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
        <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
        <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
        <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
        <option value="Jersey">Jersey</option>
        <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
        <option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
        <option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
        <option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
        <option value="South Korea">South Korea</option>
        <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
        <option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
        <option value="Laos">Laos</option>
        <option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
        <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
        <option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
        <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
        <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
        <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
        <option value="Macao">Macao</option>
        <option value="Republic of Macedonia">Republic of Macedonia</option>
        <option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
        <option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
        <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
        <option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
        <option value="Mali">Mali</option>
        <option value="Malta">Malta</option>
        <option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
        <option value="Martinique">Martinique</option>
        <option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
        <option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
        <option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option>
        <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
        <option value="Federated States of Micronesia">Federated States of Micronesia</option>
        <option value="Moldova">Moldova</option>
        <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
        <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
        <option value="Montenegro">Montenegro</option>
        <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
        <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
        <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
        <option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>
        <option value="Namibia">Namibia</option>
        <option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
        <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
        <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
        <option value="Netherlands Antilles">Netherlands Antilles</option>
        <option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
        <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
        <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
        <option value="Niger">Niger</option>
        <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
        <option value="Niue">Niue</option>
        <option value="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option>
        <option value="Northern Mariana Islands">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
        <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
        <option value="Oman">Oman</option>
        <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
        <option value="Palau">Palau</option>
        <option value="Palestine">Palestine</option>
        <option value="Panama">Panama</option>
        <option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
        <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
        <option value="Peru">Peru</option>
        <option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
        <option value="Pitcairn">Pitcairn</option>
        <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
        <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
        <option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
        <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
        <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
        <option value="Russian Federation">Russian Federation</option>
        <option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
        <option value="Réunion">Réunion</option>
        <option value="St. Barthélemy">St. Barthélemy</option>
        <option value="St. Helena, Ascension and Tristan Da Cunha">St. Helena, Ascension and Tristan Da Cunha</option>
        <option value="St. Kitts And Nevis">St. Kitts And Nevis</option>
        <option value="St. Lucia">St. Lucia</option>
        <option value="St. Martin">St. Martin</option>
        <option value="St. Pierre And Miquelon">St. Pierre And Miquelon</option>
        <option value="St. Vincent And The Grenedines">St. Vincent And The Grenedines</option>
        <option value="Samoa">Samoa</option>
        <option value="San Marino">San Marino</option>
        <option value="Sao Tome and Principe">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
        <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
        <option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
        <option value="Serbia">Serbia</option>
        <option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
        <option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option>
        <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
        <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
        <option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
        <option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
        <option value="Somalia">Somalia</option>
        <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
        <option value="South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
        <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
        <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
        <option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
        <option value="Svalbard And Jan Mayen">Svalbard And Jan Mayen</option>
        <option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
        <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
        <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
        <option value="Syrian Arab Republic">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
        <option value="Taiwan">Taiwan</option>
        <option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
        <option value="Tanzania">Tanzania</option>
        <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
        <option value="Timor-Leste">Timor-Leste</option>
        <option value="Togo">Togo</option>
        <option value="Tokelau">Tokelau</option>
        <option value="Tonga">Tonga</option>
        <option value="Trinidad and Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
        <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
        <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
        <option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
        <option value="Turks and Caicos Islands">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
        <option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
        <option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
        <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
        <option value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
        <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="United States">United States</option>
        <option value="US Minor Outlying Islands">US Minor Outlying Islands</option>
        <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
        <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
        <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
        <option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
        <option value="Viet Nam">Viet Nam</option>
        <option value="Virgin Islands, British">Virgin Islands, British</option>
        <option value="Virgin Islands, U.S.">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option>
        <option value="Wallis and Futuna">Wallis and Futuna</option>
        <option value="Western Sahara">Western Sahara</option>
        <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
        <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
    </select>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var countrySanitizer = function(formID) {
        var form = document.getElementById(formID);

        return {
            remove : function(countryArray) {
                if(countryArray.length > 0) {
                    var options = form.getElementsByTagName('option'),
                        localOptions = [];

                    //find the elements to remove
                    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i += 1)
                    {   
                        if(countryArray.indexOf(options[i].getAttribute('value')) !== -1) {
                            localOptions.push(options[i]); //push to temp array
                        }
                    }

                    //remove the entries
                    for(var y = 0; y < localOptions.length; y += 1)
                    {
                        form.removeChild(localOptions[y]);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

    };

    countrySanitizer('country').remove(
        ['Yemen','Zambia', 'Australia']
    );

    </script>
</body>
```

The HTML was taken from your page, so what you need to do is to provide the id of the form you want to strip along with chainged remove method which takes array of countries which should be removed:

```
countrySanitizer('country').remove(
        ['Yemen','Zambia', 'Australia']
    );
```

It doesn't use JQuery, it could be done with querySelector but that one isn't supported in older IE versions.